# Crystal Report Sum coming wrong

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, ms-access-2003

I made a crystal report in which i fetched out two tables data. In crystal report, I make a Detail section in which data will be show. In same section I want to show another table data. But when one table has 3 rows and 2nd table has two rows or vice versa, then new row create in a table which has less table rows. How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: How are you calculating totals, using custom formula, summary fields or running totals? It may be easy to point out if you post an image of design view also.

Comment: By using Summary Field

Comment: In advance table, i have only one row. But firstly,it showed repeatble values to fillup the rows of advance table. so i used suppress if duplicate properety for every column in advance.But now, i m facing this problem

Comment: `Suppress if Duplicated` will only hide duplicates, they will always count up in the summary. You may need to use custom formula or it would be much better if you bring only your unique records to the report, format your query or table links using `JOINS` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add running total field; sum your amount and evaluate only when first record changes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have 2 detailed tables in 1 report which is not possible unless you use subreports. From your picture i can tell that you have 2 tables (Advance and Expenses) and they are linked by some column (ammu, appu)...

Graphically this looks like this

**Table a - Advance**

```
Advance date | Advance Ammount | Model of payment | Some Column
-------------|-----------------|------------------|------------
01/02/2014   |    25000.00     |  Online          | AMMU
02/12/2014   |    15000.00     |  Debit           | APPU
and so on .....................................................
```

**Table b - Expenses**

```
Expense date | Expense Name    | Expense ammount  | Some column
-------------|-----------------|------------------|------------
20/12/2014   | Electricity bill|  2500.00         | AMMU
20/12/2014   | Telephone bill  |  1500.00         | APPU
and so on .....................................................
```

So to make this work you need to choose one of those 2 tables to be in your main report (for example table a- Advance). Then you insert group by `Some column` from table a. After that you make subreport and link to subreport is that field `some column` from table a is linked to field `some column` from table b (in your case this field has probably different name). After that you make subreport and with this done you can have 2 rows from table a and 3 rows from table b for same value of field `some column`.

I hope this helps you, if you need any additional information about how to do it feel free to ask. This is just an idea how to solve your problem. I'm sure there are many other ways to do it so no need to stick on this solution.